# How to check for a value's datatype inside django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to get the datatype of a value in django template. I am sure there is a way because when you do
`value|date:"Y-m-d"`
django template understands that the value is timestamp. How does django do it?

Comment: Template doesn't know datatype of value. `date` filter expects correct  datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "|date" you see is called a [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) and is a built-in function of django

you may want to create one of your own ([here's how](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)) that takes something as input and returns its datatype.

but, imo, it's not a best-practice, since a template should mostly be used to just display and format data. if you need an evaluation on the type i suggest you move that inside a view and return the result in the context, eventually

Comment: `date` is not a tag, it is a filter

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, my bad on that. i'll edit the answer with the correct information, i just used a "shortcut" from the docs (section template-tags) to identify them both, but it's just my convention. :)